# Why is my ElapsedMilliseconds always zero here?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, data-structures

So I'm trying to measure the performance of the hash set I created versus the performance of the same elements in a `List` and in the following block of code

```
        Stopwatch Watch = new Stopwatch();
        long tList = 0, tHset = 0; // ms
        foreach ( string Str in Copy )
        {
            // measure time to look up string in ordinary list
            Watch.Start();
            if ( ListVersion.Contains(Str) ) { }
            Watch.Stop();
            tList += Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            // now measure time to look up same string in my hash set
            Watch.Reset();
            Watch.Start();
            if ( this.Contains(Str) ) { }
            Watch.Stop();
            tHset += Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Watch.Reset();
        }
        int n = Copy.Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Average milliseconds to look up in List: {0}", tList / n);
        Console.WriteLine("Average milliseconds to look up in hashset: {0}", tHset / n);
```

it is outputing `0` for both. Any idea why this is? Relevant documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because the operations are too fast and you shouldn't measure performance like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the operation is faster than precision of the `Stapwatch`.

Instead of measuring each of the `Contains` call separately measure a group of them:

```
Stopwatch Watch = new Stopwatch();
long tList = 0, tHset = 0; // ms

// measure time to look up string in ordinary list
Watch.Start();
foreach ( string Str in Copy )
{
    if ( ListVersion.Contains(Str) ) { }
}
Watch.Stop();
tList = Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
// now measure time to look up same string in my hash set
Watch.Reset();
Watch.Start();
foreach ( string Str in Copy )
{
    if ( this.Contains(Str) ) { }
}
Watch.Stop();
tHset = Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

Console.WriteLine("Total milliseconds to look up in List: {0}", tList);
Console.WriteLine("Total milliseconds to look up in hashset: {0}", tHset);
```

As you can see, I also changed the code to print total time spent instead of average. With operations so fast performance is usually presented in Xs per Y operations instead of average. E.g. 40ms per 10 million lookups.

Also, it's possible that in Release mode parts of your code will be optimized away, because it doesn't actually do anything. Consider counting number of elements for which `Contains` returns true and printing that number out at the end.

Comment: Huh? My compiler would be stupid if it assumed that my `if` statements don't accomplish anything in the program

Comment: @user6048670 But your if does nothing.  How is the compiler stupid if it recognizes that?

Comment: It would have to be a very smart compiler to understand that a call to the container's `Contains` method has no side effects. I doubt that the assembly metadata contains enough information to tell the compiler something like that.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep your code as it is and instead of doing :

```
Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

You do this :

```
Watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

This way you will have the fractional part of the millisecond